# Laravel 8 image upload: Best practices for storing and editing image files

Tags: php, laravel

I need assistance to more understand the concept so I can become a better developer. I want to learn how to refactor the code and erase all duplications.

What's the best practices for image uploads? Renaming them correctly?

I have a block of code that handles two attachments:

```
if( $request->hasFile('LFImage') ) {
            $destination = public_path('app/lostFound/lostItems' . $lostFound->LFImage);
            if( File::exists($destination) )
            {
                File::delete($destination);
            }
            $file = $request->file('LFImage');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $lostFound->LFNumber . '-' . $lostFound->lostItem . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('app/lostFound/lostItems', $filename);
            $lostFound->LFImage = $filename;

        }
        if( $request->hasFile('handoverStatement') ) {
            $destination = public_path('app/lostFound/handoverStatements' . $lostFound->handoverStatement);
            if( File::exists($destination) )
            {
                File::delete($destination);
            }
            $file = $request->file('handoverStatement');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $lostFound->lostItem . '-' . $lostFound->LFNumber . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('app/lostFound/handoverStatements', $filename);
            $lostFound->handoverStatement = $filename;
        }
```

They're exactly the same except with the upload directory.
How can I make it as a one code block across the entire application with changeable file name and location depending on the form?

Some file names require random strings, how can I "Edit" the random string to the file that was uploaded?

Comment: use Spatie medialibrary https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Best practice when uploading and storing files in Laravel is using [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem).

It has all needed methods to work with files, you can save the file like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::put('images/', $request->file('LFImage'));
```

In the documentation provided above, you can find other examples like renaming and moving files

In order to access these files from web as well, you can use the command `php artisan storage:link`, which creates a symbolic link to storage folder in your public folder. After you create the symbolic link, you can generate URL to the file like this:

```
asset('storage/test.txt')
```

To avoid duplications, you can create a function in your controller to create a file. You will then just call this function with different files to keep the file creation code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write this

```
if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
    deleteImageFromDirectory(setting('logo'), "Settings");
    $data['logo'] =  uploadImageToDirectory( $request->logo , "Settings");
}
```

and define uploadImageToDirectory function in your helper functions or create a trait

```
function uploadImageToDirectory($imageFile, $directory = '' ){
   $imageName = $imageFile->getClientOriginalName();  // Set Image name
   $imageFile->storeAs("/Images/$directory", $imageName, 'public');
   return $imageName;
}
```